# Android Flow example crashes with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse, mortar, square-flow

I'm Naive in Android development. I tried to use flow/mortar for development and stuck with an exception.

Here's what I did. In Eclipse, I chose New (Crtl N) -> Android Project from existing code and imported the flow sample downloaded from the square flow website https://github.com/square/flow/. 
Eclipse marked errors in all the files as the package name was not matching the file's location. So to fix the package mismatch issue, I moved the files 
from   : \flow-master\flow-sample\src**\main\java\com\example\flow** 
to     : \flow-master\flow-sample\src**\com\example\flow.**

After this, I got some more errors saying 'Unresolved to a Type' which I fixed by importing proper jar files. Now all the errors are cleared and I tried to install and launch the app.

The app crashes as soon as we launch with the Logcat error below:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flow/com.example.flow.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.flow.MainActivity  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1888)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1989)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1155)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.flow.MainActivity
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)  
 E/AndroidRuntime(5438):    ... 11 more
```

The error says that the file `MainActivity` is not found even when the file is available in the path `com.example.flow.`. Can someone please help me understand what the issue is?

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.flow"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">
          <uses-sdk
              android:minSdkVersion="14"
              android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

          <application
              android:icon="@drawable/flow_icon">
            <activity
                android:label="Flow"
                android:name="com.example.flow.MainActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
              </intent-filter>
            </activity>
          </application>
        </manifest>
```

Comment: Did you change the path in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: Show your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: '<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="**com.example.flow**"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk minSdkVersion="14" targetSdkVersion="18"/>
  <application android:icon="@drawable/flow_icon">
    <activity
        android:label="Flow"
        android:name="**com.example.flow.MainActivity**">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>'